# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE when running npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm

Every time I run npm install on my boilerplate project I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in multi react-color moment ag-grid ag-grid-react es6-promise react-dom-factories react-spinners sortablejs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-spinners' in 'C:\Code\react-boilerplate'
 @ multi react-color moment ag-grid ag-grid-react es6-promise react-dom-factories react-spinners sortablejs vendor[6]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @myapp/app@0.0.1 build: `webpack --config ./webpack.prod.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @myapp/app@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-18T01_29_52_633Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @myapp/app@0.0.1 prepare: `npm run build && npm run build:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @myapp/app@0.0.1 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-18T01_29_52_874Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

After running `npm install -S react-spinners && npm install` getting this:

```
ERROR in multi react-color moment ag-grid ag-grid-react es6-promise react-dom-factories react-spinners sortablejs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sortablejs' in 'C:\Code\react-boilerplate'
 @ multi react-color moment ag-grid ag-grid-react es6-promise react-dom-factories react-spinners sortablejs vendor[7]
```

Comment: Try removing `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Try `npm install -S react-spinners && npm install`

Comment: Tried it, now getting another error. updated original post with it.

Comment: Read the error message. It is telling you that you don't have `sortablejs` installed.

Comment: Ah that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Did I get the errors because some of my packages had react-spinners and sortablejs as their internal dependency?

Comment: It might be that some other package had `react-spinners` and `sortablejs` as `peerDependecies`, yes. Or you might have installed those earlier without adding them to your `package.json` dependencies, so reinstalling would cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are telling you that you don't have `react-spinners` and `sortablejs` installed. You can install them and add them to your `dependencies` and it will work:

```
npm i -S react-spinners sortablejs && npm install
```

It might be that some other package had `react-spinners` and `sortablejs` as `peerDependecies`, or you might have installed those earlier without adding them to your `dependencies`, which would give rise to your errors if you remove `node_modules` and reinstall.

Comment: Both `react-spinners` and `sortablejs` are dependencies in my package.json file. So why do I need to install them first and before running npm i. PS. I'm aware that the issue is solved but its just something thats been nagging me.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I'm not quite sure. Do you still get the error if you remove the entire `node_modules` directory and install everything from scratch? `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`